# dart compute Illegal argument in isolate message

Tags: dart, isolate

I am using compute to do some work while keeping the UI running. The `compute` was working until I added another http call before it.

The working code is as follow

```
final ListRequest request =
        ListRequest(baseUrl: env['SERVER_URL']!, path: '/Items');

_mainController.updateListItems(
        await compute(_service.getItems, request));
```

I read some articles saying the function `compute` calls should be a top level function or a static function. However, the `getItems` is an instance function and there was no exception.

Recently I added a few lines and the code became

```
final Filter? filter = await _service.getFilter();

final ListRequest request =
        ListRequest(baseUrl: env['SERVER_URL']!, path: '/Items');

request.filter = filter;

_mainController.updateListItems(
        await compute(_service.getItems, request));
```

`getFilter` is a http call to retrieve some filter parameters from the backend.

Then I got the following error

```
Invalid argument(s): Illegal argument in isolate message: (object extends NativeWrapper - Library:'dart:io' Class: _SecureFilterImpl@13069316)
```

My dart and flutter versions are

```
Dart SDK version: 2.15.1 (stable)
Flutter 2.8.1
```

Thank you

=========================================================

**Update**

The Filter is

```
Filter {
  String? itemLocationSuburb;
  String? itemLocationPostcode;
}
```

Comment: Can you provide the definition for the `Filter` class? My guess is that `Filter` has a property of a type that is not supported by [SendPort.send](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.17.3/dart-isolate/SendPort/send.html).

Comment: Hi @mmcdon20, thank you for your advice. I added the implementation of Filter. Both of them are nullable string so not sure what could be wrong.

Comment: Nullable Strings should work fine, so I guess that isn't it. Is it possible to create a [minimal complete reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: Thank you @mmcdon20, I will come back when the example is created.

Answer (score 0):

Your `_service` service presumably contains a `HttpClient`. When you make a request through this client, it opens a connection to the HTTP server, and may maintain the connection after the request completes.

The `HttpClient` cannot be sent through a `SendPort` when it has open connections, but it is included in the scope of the `getItems` method.

To work around this issue, you can do one of the following:

- Disable persistent connections with the [`HttpClientRequest.persistentConnection`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.17.5/dart-io/HttpClientRequest/persistentConnection.html) property
- Make a new `HttpClient` to send through the compute function every time
- Implement a long-lived background isolate to maintain its own `HttpClient`
- Use the `HttpClient` in the main isolate, and only perform other work like parsing with `compute` (there's no significant benefit to using an isolate to make HTTP requests anyway)